# (Python 3) imaplib logins from .txt file

Tags: python, file, while-loop, imap, imaplib

In a file called "emails.txt" I have few accounts in this format - `email:pw`.
I've already done split, and everything works perfect, but only if there is only one `account:pw` in the list.

If I put 2 or more, I'm getting Login failed on first account.

Here's code (login and function, not included)

```
with open('emails.txt') as emails:
    for line in emails:

        EMAIL_ACCOUNT = line.split(":", -2)[-2]
        PASSWORD = line.split(":", 1)[1]

        print(PASSWORD)

        EMAIL_FOLDER = "INBOX"

        M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmx.com')

        try:
            rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            print("Failed!" + EMAIL_ACCOUNT)
            sys.exit(1)
            time.sleep()
        M.logout()
```

What should I do, to make it:

- 1. Login from first account from list, and do the job
- 2. Login from second account from list, and do the job etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't supply an example `emails.txt` file, I'll resort to guessing what actually happens.
Sorry if this turns out to be wrong!

Note that the lines in `for line in emails:` do include the trailing line break.
Perhaps you don't insert a line break after the end of the last line when editing (which can cause problems with automation later, but that's beside the point).

So, when you have a file `email1:password1` (no line break after the password), everything is fine.
When you instead have a file `email1:password1\nemail2:password2` (here, `\n` is the line break), your program sees the password for the first email as `password1\n` instead of just `password1`.

One way to get the trailing newline character removed is to use `strip()` function, like this: `PASSWORD = line.split(":", 1)[1].strip()`.

---

*Also, it can be a good habit to follow the definition "a line is something which ends with a line break", i.e., add a line break after the last line, too. This can achieve uniformity, simplify automation, and remove corner cases. But I digress.*

Comment: Thank you! .strip() did the job!